# how to check checkbox status on change event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, checkbox

In my login page, I have a checkbox, that has to do something on change event,I have wrote change event in my js and I have to check whether it is checked or unchecked, I have used many methods like

`$(".checkbox").is(":checked")`/

`$(".checkbox").attr("checked")`/

`$(".checkbox").prop("checked")`

but all the above are not working, the last two return undefined where as the first one returns false always.
I have fiddled this [here](https://jsfiddle.net/iamshajeer/mhs95fcv/)
.please help me to figure out the error

**html**

```
              <div class="checkbox">
                    <label>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="checkbox" runat="server" cssClass="remember-me" Checked="false" />
                        Remember Me
                    </label>                  
                </div>
```

**js**

```
   $(document).ready(function () {

       $('.remember-me').change(function () {
           alert($(".remember-me").is(":checked"));
       });

   });
```

Comment: Use `#checkbox` instead of `.remember-me` then it works.

Comment: Besides it would be better to put your code in question.

Comment: @SAM please reload the qn, I have edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are checking if the label is checked, not the input.

```js
$('#checkbox').on("change", function() {
alert($(this).is(":checked"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label>
  <span class="remember-me">
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="checkbox">
        </span>
  Remember Me</label>
```

Comment: Please checked as a correct answer if your issue solved.

Comment: @epasca anyway I have got the answer. I havent noticed the html conversion of aspx file. thanx a lot

Answer (score 0):

Change your JQuery to:

```
   $('#checkbox').change(function () {
       alert($("#checkbox").is(":checked"));
   });
```

Or:

```
alert($( "#checkbox" ).prop( "checked" ));
```

Comment: can you reload the qn, there is a little change in qn